# Using Gradle (build.gradle) to run ANT build.xml file

Tags: gradle, ant, build.gradle, build.xml

What am I doing wrong?? It's not running my [build.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfzR6.png).

Also, how would I be able to express the existing Ant logic in Gradle?
Ex: Changing a build.xml to build.gradle and be able to have the same out put when compiled.

[--Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opuFh.png)

Comment: Please provide some additional context and details.  Put your error, in text, here in the question, and explicitly define what you're trying to achieve.  Linking an image, alone, is not typically enough for a [suitable question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle allows you to import a full Ant build.

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
```

Effectively this turns Ant targets into Gradle tasks which can be executed from the command line. Please see the [Gradle user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html#sec:import_ant_build) for more information.

Comment: Is there a way to fully convert the build.xml file to a build.gradle?

Comment: No, at the moment there is no automated way to convert an Ant file into a Gradle file.

Comment: Of course. You'd have to know how to express the existing Ant logic in Gradle though.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link that can explain the logic of Ant and Gradle?

Comment: I already added the link in my post. Furthermore, the [free chapter 9 in "Gradle in Action"](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/3/2f57917-4c66-4017-b441-0662e9508608/GradleinAction_CH09.pdf) might help to understand the interaction between Ant and Gradle.

Comment: I have a task named "package" but when I run it it gives me an error. But when I renamed it to "rackage" it works fine. Also Create-War would give me an error saying create is not found, and if I change Create-War to "CreateWar" it would also work find. Would you know why is this happening?

Comment: In Gradle the default convention for naming tasks is camel-case notation. I'd try to stick to it as much as possible. Regarding the `package` task please run the build with `-s` and post the stack trace.

Comment: Posted, Is there a place where we can talk? I am looking at your pdf file and it is very simliar on what I have to do. But there are some tags I cant figure out how to translate into gradle.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen that your build.xml may not be on the classpath. Please check it once.
Thanks